# Termo técnico `Spaced Repetition` em português

Tags: tradução-inglês, expressões-equivalentes, termos-em-inglês

**Qual a melhor tradução do termo técnico `Spaced Repetition` para Português?**

A expressão original em inglês na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition), em tradução livre feita por mim, poderia ser resumida como:

> *Spaced repetition* é uma técnica de aprendizado que incorpora intervalos crescentes de tempo entre a revisão subseqüente do material previamente aprendido, a fim de explorar o *spacing effect*  de psicologia. Nomes alternativos incluem ensaio espaçado, ensaio de expansão, intervalos graduados, espaçamento de repetição, programação de repetição, recuperação espaçada e recuperação expandida.

Por ser um termo técnico, é importante que haja um cuidado maior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tradução mais natural, "`repetição espaçada`", parece ser também a mais usada, de acordo com os (poucos) textos do [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com.br/portugues-ingles/search?source=auto&query=%22spaced+repetition%22), com pelo menos uma empresa de ensino de idiomas ([Mosalingua](https://www.mosalingua.com/pt/o-sistema-de-repeticao-espacada-memorizar-para-jamais-esquecer/)), e com um [trabalho acadêmico](https://app.uff.br/riuff/bitstream/1/5633/1/TCC_DIMITRI_COUTO_LAMERI.pdf) de encerramento de curso.

Também na Wikipedia, o "*spacing effect*" (fenômeno de aprendizagem explorado na técnica de "*spaced repetition*") é traduzido como [Efeito de Espaçamento](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efeito_do_espa%C3%A7amento).

Outra possibilidade bastante usada é manter o termo em inglês mesmo.

Comment: Não gosto de deixar termos em inglês. Porém, concordo com a sua resposta,

Comment: @Lambie Sim, é bem traduzível. Se se tratar de um texto (e não, e.g., um item de menu de aplicativo), minha preferência seria por usar a tradução, mencionando o termo original em inglês ao introduzi-la.

Comment: Acho que nem sempre seja necessário mencionar o original. Só quando o conceito não faz sentido. Aqui faz.

Comment: Ah, sim, não tem que se citar sempre. Eu só faria para deixar o leitor já acostumado à expressão em inglês seguro de fato era uma simples tradução e não um novo conceito.

Comment: Essa é uma tradução do jogo https://ncase.me/remember/, mas a discussão aberta está em https://github.com/fititnt/remember/pull/1. Também concordo que pode valer a pena deixar em inglês, porém nesse contexto o próprio termo é explicado (e muito provavelmente isso acabará gerando entrada na Wikipedia). Então por isso da importância de ir mais atrás.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Na minha opinião, o verbete da Wikipedia deveria ser em português - eu diria que a tradução é bastante inconteste. O jogo me parece ter bastante texto, então me parece viável mencionar o original em inglês quando o conceito for introduzido, como: "...repetição espaçada (do inglês *spaced repetition*)...".

Comment: @stafusa sim, no caso do jogo e nesse contexto, faz sentido manter em português, justamente porque tem-se possibilidade de adicionar mais contexto. Porém na resposta sugerir que seria possibilidade manter em inglês também seria viável em outros casos, ou pelo menos sinaliza a quem vier aqui que pode valer a pena citar tradução e original.

Comment: Eu ainda usaria repetição com intervalo ou repetição intervalada. Isso daria a ideia de tempo, diferente da tradução repetição espaçada que é mais literal. Mas nesse site que tem a versão em EN e Português, é traduzido para Repetição espaçada -> https://www.kde.org/announcements/announce-4.0.3-pt_BR.php

Comment: @Peixoto, "intervalado" é mesmo outra opção. Mas acho que você se engana quanto à diferença de significado - na minha experiência (e também de acordo com o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/espa%C3%A7ado)), "espaçado" significa `Intervalo, quanto ao tempo e ao espaço.`. Inclusive, a diferença, sutil, que vejo entre as duas palavras nesse contexto é que "intervalado" parece dar uma ênfase indevida à interrupção do estudo, enquanto "espaçado" dá a ênfase, ao meu ver mais correta, de ter-se o estudo distribuído ao longo do tempo, ao invés de concentrado.